# Quebra de linha com css sem <br>

Tags: html, css, text, quebras-de-linha

Estou com esse problema em css e não consigo resolver, quando o texto fica grande de mais, não consigo fazer essa linha quebrar, não posso usar o , alguém tem alguma ideia? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-chat {
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(100% - 55px);
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: solid 4px transparent;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.balao {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  background: #2f8633;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.balao h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.balao p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-mins-chat {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f8633;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-mins-chat button {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  background: #4caf50;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-mins-chat input[type=text] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
  border: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-chat" id="pagina">

  <!--<?php  $result = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT user, msg, id FROM chat"); ?>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : ?>-->
  <div class="balao">
    <h1>
      nome do usuario
      <!--<?= $row['user']; ?>-->
    </h1>
    <p>
      mensagem
      <!--<?= $row['msg']; ?>-->
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--<?php endwhile; ?>-->
</div>
<form class="form-mins-chat" name='singup' method="post" action="chatdb.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>">
  <input type="text" name="msg">
  <button type="submit" value="deletar"><span class="ion-android-send">></span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Ou

```
word-break: break-word;
```

#### Referências

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: word-break: break-word; deu certinho, obrigado.